# How can I collect the calendar period?

Tags: jsp, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I have made a Fullcalendar like this one:

```
$(function() {
         $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         defaultView: 'timelineMonth',
         resourceAreaWidth : 100,
         resourceLabelText: 'Site - Usine',
         resources: dataJSON

      });
});
```

I want to collect the calendar period in my .jsp file to loop on the dates of the month.
How can I do it?

Comment: you mean you want to know the start and end dates of the current calendar display, so that you can output the correct events from your server? If so, please read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-function - these are two different ways that you can connect fullCalendar to a server to download events.

Comment: In the first case ("events as JSON") fullCalendar automatically makes a request to the URL you provide, and automatically puts start and end date parameters in the request. In the second case ("events as function"), you have to make the request yourself (within the callback function) but as you will see, fullCalendar provides you the start and end dates in parameters given to the function, so you can send them to the server in whatever way you like. This second case is there to give you more flexibility if, for some reason, your server cannot be directly compatible with the JSON requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser.

I don't understand how you want me to send the start and end date.

I have to make an ajax request, right?
And what do I take as a value to send to the server?

`$.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/ALMA/Production/SegeparEfficiency/DailySegeparEfficiencyArchivedJSONServlet",
        data: {
         start : start,
         end : end
        },
       
        success: function(data) { 
        }
    });`

Comment: yes you could do it like that if you want. If you're using the events-as-function option, then the point is, it's up to you, you can send the dates in whatever way your server will accept them. Fullcalendar gives you the dates...what you do after that is your decision. (But if you use the events-as-JSON option, then fullCalendar will send the dates for you automatically.)

Comment: Sorry,

But I don't understand how it works the events-as-fuction option.

For send the dates on my server.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: In your calendar setup you could write something like `events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { $.ajax({ dataType: "json", url: "/ALMA/Production/SegeparEfficiency/DailySegeparEfficiencyArchivedJSONServlet", data: { start : start.format("YYYY-MM-DD"), end : end.format("YYYY-MM-DD") }, success: function(data) { callback(data) } });}`.

Comment: So this means that whenever fullCalendar needs new events (because calendar is loading, or because the user changed the date), it will run this function you are providing. The `start` and `end` dates required are given to the function in its parameters, each time it runs. Your ajax request can then use them to send to your server. The server can receive them, use them to send back a list of events (in JSON format) occurring between those dates, and when AJAX receives them back, it uses the provided `callback` parameter (which is a function reference), to pass the event data to fullCalendar.

Comment: Good, it's works !

Thank's

Answer (score -1):

Try similar to this

```
  function getDateRange() {
        var startdate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start.format('DD MMM YYYY');
        var enddate = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end.format('DD MMM YYYY');
        var dates = { startdate: startdate, enddate: enddate };
        return dates;
    }
```

Comment: This is kind-of true, but a) I think OP wants to know the dates so that the server can send the right events, and there are better ways to do that (see my comments above), and b), the `_d` property is an internal one and not intended for use. `start` and `end` are momentJS objects and as such they have functions which allow you to output a date in many different formats, without using internal properties whose behaviour is not well-defined. See https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, 
but I have a Javascript error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'start' of undefined

Comment: It still doesn't really help with actually sending the date to the server for the purpose of downloading events though, does it? Like I said, fullcalendar provides better ways to do this job - see my comments on the main question, above.